# Web Scraper for Data-Url in Div Python (BeautifulSoup)

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

### I don't know why the program doesn't extract the links from inside the div

*I don't know if the error was in defining the div class or the code at the stage of extracting the data-url from the div*

here is the current code :

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

header = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36"
}

url = requests.get("https://www.chosic.com/free-music/all/" , headers=header)
soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, 'lxml')

list = []

music = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'track-audio'})
for i in music:
    i.findAll(['data-url'])
    print(i)
```

### output :

```
<div class="track-audio"><div class="waveform before" data-saved="yes" data-track="27306" data-url="https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/happy-clappy-ukulele.mp3" id="waveform27306"></div></div>
<div class="track-audio"><div class="waveform before" data-saved="yes" data-track="25944" data-url="https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Art-Of-Silence_V2.mp3" id="waveform25944"></div></div>
<div class="track-audio"><div class="waveform before" data-saved="yes" data-track="26757" data-url="https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/batchbug-sweet-dreams.mp3" id="waveform26757"></div></div>
<div class="track-audio"><div class="waveform before" data-saved="yes" data-track="27880" data-url="https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Luke-Bergs-Bliss.mp3" id="waveform27880"></div></div>
<div class="track-audio"><div class="waveform before" data-saved="yes" data-track="27281" data-url="https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/Warm-Memories-Emotional-Inspiring-Piano.mp3" id="waveform27281"></div></div>
<div class="track-audio"><div class="waveform before" data-saved="yes" data-track="26021" data-url="https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/fm-freemusic-give-me-a-smile.mp3" id="waveform26021"></div></div>
<div class="track-audio"><div class="waveform before" data-saved="yes" data-track="27247" data-url="https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/Monkeys-Spinning-Monkeys.mp3" id="waveform27247"></div></div>
<div class="track-audio"><div class="waveform before" data-saved="yes" data-track="27248" data-url="https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/Fluffing-a-Duck.mp3" id="waveform27248"></div></div>
<div class="track-audio"><div class="waveform before" data-saved="yes" data-track="27120" data-url="https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/fm-freemusic-inspiring-optimistic-upbeat-energetic-guitar-rhythm.mp3" id="waveform27120"></div></div>
<div class="track-audio"><div class="waveform before" data-saved="yes" data-track="25860" data-url="https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/alexander-nakarada-superepic.mp3" id="waveform25860"></div></div>
<div class="track-audio"><div class="waveform before" data-saved="yes" data-track="28703" data-url="https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/An-Epic-Story.mp3" id="waveform28703"></div></div>
<div class="track-audio"><div class="waveform before" data-saved="yes" data-track="28923" data-url="https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/scott-buckley-jul.mp3" id="waveform28923"></div></div>
<div class="track-audio"><div class="waveform before" data-saved="yes" data-track="24515" data-url="https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/John_Bartmann_-_02_-_Happy_African_Village.mp3" id="waveform24515"></div></div>
<div class="track-audio"><div class="waveform before" data-saved="yes" data-track="27012" data-url="https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/春
のテーマ-Spring-field-.mp3" id="waveform27012"></div></div>
<div class="track-audio"><div class="waveform before" data-saved="yes" data-track="25897" data-url="https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Brandenburg-Concerto-no.-3-BWV-1048-Complete-Performance.mp3" id="waveform25897"></div></div>
```

but i want extract their `data-url` from `div`

---

### example :

---

```
https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Luke-Bergs-Bliss.mp3
https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/Warm-Memories-Emotional-Inspiring-Piano.mp3
https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/fm-freemusic-give-me-a-smile.mp3
https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/Monkeys-Spinning-Monkeys.mp3
https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/Fluffing-a-Duck.mp3
https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/fm-freemusic-inspiring-optimistic-upbeat-energetic-guitar-rhythm.mp3
https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/alexander-nakarada-superepic.mp3
https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/An-Epic-Story.mp3
https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/scott-buckley-jul.mp3
https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/John_Bartmann_-_02_-_Happy_African_Village.mp3
https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/春
のテーマ-Spring-field-.mp3
https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Brandenburg-Concerto-no.-3-BWV-1048-Complete-Performance.mp3
```

***any solution possible ??***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.findAll` doesn't accept CSS-selectors. Also, you aren't assigning the output from `.findAll` to anything. Try:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

header = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36"
}

url = requests.get("https://www.chosic.com/free-music/all/", headers=header)
soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, "lxml")

music = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "track-audio"})
for i in music:
    m = i.select_one("[data-url]")
    print(m["data-url"])
```

Prints:

```
https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/happy-clappy-ukulele.mp3
https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Art-Of-Silence_V2.mp3
https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/batchbug-sweet-dreams.mp3
https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Luke-Bergs-Bliss.mp3
https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/Warm-Memories-Emotional-Inspiring-Piano.mp3
https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/fm-freemusic-give-me-a-smile.mp3
https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/Monkeys-Spinning-Monkeys.mp3
https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/Fluffing-a-Duck.mp3
https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/fm-freemusic-inspiring-optimistic-upbeat-energetic-guitar-rhythm.mp3
https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/alexander-nakarada-superepic.mp3
https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/An-Epic-Story.mp3
https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/scott-buckley-jul.mp3
https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/John_Bartmann_-_02_-_Happy_African_Village.mp3
https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/春のテーマ-Spring-field-.mp3
https://www.chosic.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/Brandenburg-Concerto-no.-3-BWV-1048-Complete-Performance.mp3
```

Comment: Can you explain to me what it means? 
m = i.select_one("[data-url]")
    print(m["data-url"])

Comment: @hfwassim `i.select_one("[data-url]")` will find any tag with attribute `data-url=` inside the `<div>` tag stored in variable `i`.  `print(m["data-url"])` will just print value of this attribute.